# Is there a way to limit / page result sets

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

Is there a way to limit / page result sets using GetAllWithChildren() or GetAll() or GetAllWithChildrenAsync() or GetAllAsync().

These methods accept a filtering expression but it doesn't appear that there is any straightforward way of setting an explicit limiter or orderby clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetAllWithChildren` method is just a convenience method. To perform custom queries you have to use the `Table` method. It shouldn't be difficult to implement your own fetch method with the functionality that you want extending the already existing `GetAllWithChildren`:

```
public static class OrderExtensions {
    public static List<T> GetAllWithChildren<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn,
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Expression<Func<T, object>> orderExpr = null,
            int? limit = null,
            int? offset = null,
            bool recursive = false) where T: class
    {
        var elements = conn.Table<T>();
        if (filter != null) {
            elements = elements.Where(filter);
        }
        if (orderExpr != null) {
            elements = elements.OrderBy(orderExpr);
        }
        if (offset != null) {
            elements = elements.Skip(offset.Value);
        }
        if (limit != null) {
            elements = elements.Take(limit.Value);
        }

        var list = elements.ToList();

        foreach (T element in list)
        {
            conn.GetChildren(element, recursive);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
    conn.GetAllWithChildren<MyClass>(
            filter: o => o.Name != "",
            orderBy: o => o.Name,
            limit: 10, offset: 20);
```

or the less verbose (and less descriptive) version:

```
    conn.GetAllWithChildren<MyClass>(o => o.Name != "", o => o.Name, 10, 20);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. for anyone else reading.
elements.Skip(offset.Value); should be elements = elements.Skip(offset.Value);

otherwise skip is ignored. same with take.

Comment: Updated answer, nice catch.